# Ruby: Require a file again if it is changed

Tags: ruby, require

I've written a gem that looks in `config/` for a config file. This works fine but if the user changes any config they have to stop the program and start it again before my gem loads the new config. This would require them to restart the whole rails app on every change, which isn't ideal.

Is there a way to "re-require" a file so that it loads it up fresh instead of using the cached version.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use `load` instead of `require`. This will load the file regardless of whether it was already loaded before. Note that with `load` you need to specify the `.rb` extension which is optional with `require`. So `require "path/to/myconfig"` becomes `load "path/to/myconfig.rb"`.

Note that this will not undefine anything defined by the previous config. So if the config is changed from `$verbose = true; $debug = true` to `$verbose = false` then `$verbose` will be `false` but `$debug` will still be `true` after reloading the config.

Of course you'll need to put the `load` statement somewhere where it will be executed every time the config file should be reloaded (i.e. inside some method or hook).

Comment: I've noticed that with `load`, I have to specify the file extension (.rb), while with `require`, I just specify the filename. Maybe this'll help someone!